# Android TextView on a widget: How to fit number of lines to TextView height while adding ellipsis on overflow?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, textview

I have a widget that has a TextView of variable size based on the size of the parent, which ultimately descends from the size of the widget as adjusted by the user. I'd like the TextView to display as much text as possible, and then show ellipsis for the text that overflows the size of the TextView.

As far as I can tell, the `android:ellipsize` property only works if the number of lines is limited. If the lines aren't limited, then the text simply flows off the end of the TextView and is cut off.

However, since the size of the TextView is variable, limiting the number of lines using the

```
android:lines
```

or

```
android:maxLines
```

properties doesn't work for me.

I've seen a solution that involves adding a GlobalLayoutListener that dynamically calculates the number of lines that fit and then setting the lines to match, but that doesn't work in my case because the TextView is on a widget and I can't add a GlobalLayoutListener.

Is there any way that I can support multiple widget sizes/screen sizes/font sizes while simultaneously not allowing the text to overflow the container?

Edit: Here is my layout, in edited relevant part (I've removed irrelevant lines like color and moved in some style information like textSize):

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:gravity="top"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
                  android:background="@drawable/widget_frame"
                  android:paddingTop="3.0dip"
                  android:paddingBottom="5.0dip"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView android:textSize="@dimen/widget_text"
          android:id="@+id/widget_text_view"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:text="@string/widget_loading"
          android:textSize="14.0sp"
          android:ellipsize="end" />
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: @HamidShatu I added the layout of the TextView. Let me know if seeing more of the rest of the layout would be helpful.

Comment: please, post rest layout XML which will help to understand relation of `TextView` with other views.

Comment: @HamidShatu Added the full layout

Comment: did you use `android:maxLines` with `android:ellipsize="end"` in the `TextView`?

Comment: @HamidShatu Yes, it works with the ellipsis when the lines are limited, but then when the widget is bigger, the text doesn't expand to fill the increased space.

Comment: If you set `android:layout_height` to `match_parent` and then set `android:ellipsize="end"`, the `ellipsize` will not work and text of the `TextView` will be cut-off. This is what I observed after trying to solve your problem.

Comment: @HamidShatu What would you suggest then for a TextView in a widget that I want to display as much content as possible depending on the space available, and then to gracefully cut off the text with an ellipsis rather than simply cutting off with truncation?